# Making 3rd party jar use class from a different 3rd party jar

Tags: java, jar, ant, classpath

My problem is that i want to make one jar use classes from a different jar and i could not find how to do it.

I have 2 jars: `version1.jar` and `version1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Both jars have the class `com.bet.util.CustomConnection` inside them.
Only `version1.jar` has the class `ConnectionManager` available. The `ConnectionManager` class uses the `CustomConnection` class.

In jar `version1-SNAPSHOT.jar` the class `CustomConnection` has some methods which i need, jar `version1.jar` does not have them implemented.

I want to use the `ConnectionManager` class and make it use the `CustomConnection` class from the other ( `version1-SNAPSHOT.jar` ) jar.

I am using `ant` for building the process. 
I cannot modify any of the jars.

Is this possible?

Comment: What happens if you put `version1-SNAPSHOT.jar` before `version1.jar` on the classpath?

Comment: Why do you need both? Can't you just use the latest version, the snapshot one?

Comment: @GhostCat the snapshot one does not have the ConnectionManager class, which i need. the reason why i can't change the jars is beacuse this is old code... too old and nobody has the source code.

Comment: @Slaw i tried reordering the jars in the classpath and was expecting it to work but it didn't

Comment: Then, if license allows for that, I would extract both jars, and manually merge the classes you want, and wrap those up in a new single jar.